# I want to generate a custom I'd with a combination of first name,last name and number

Tags: mysql

Now, the rule that we'd planned for the UID (Unique Membership Num/ Customer Num) to be auto-generated each time a user registers (account is created).

The rule we'd set:
FirstName LastName = FL+ 001 
(the number associated with those two letters in chronological order of account creation)ie both letters are unique and only when both are repeated, should the number count go up.

eg:

```
John Doe - JD001
John Denver - JD002
Jane Foster - JF001
Bob Bilkins - BB001
Bill Graham - BG001
```

Comment: Are you having specific trouble achieving this? What have you tried and what's going wrong?

Comment: can you show us your code so far?

Comment: What comes after `JS999`? And what is your question?

Comment: I don't like customer numbers that don't have a check digit - it's far to easy to type jd002 instead of jd001;

Comment: @showdev i do not know where to begin or how to go about this,can you please help me or share a demo code to help me out?? Thanks.

Comment: @Hemant                                                                                                                    CREATE TABLE table1_seq
(
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
);
CREATE TABLE table1
(
  id VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT '0', name VARCHAR(30)
);
Now the trigger

DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER tg_table1_insert
BEFORE INSERT ON table1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO table1_seq VALUES (NULL);
  SET NEW.id = CONCAT('LHPL', LPAD(LAST_INSERT_ID(), 3, '0'));
END$$
DELIMITER ;  but this just adds lhpl.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `users` table would be:

```
create table users (
  user_id int unsigned auto_increment primary key,
  fname varchar(50) not null,
  lname varchar(50) not null,
  uid varchar(50) unique
);
```

Create another table, which will hold last sequence numbers for all user initials:

```
create table uid_seq (
  initials varchar(2) not null primary key,
  seq int unsigned not null
);
```

Then write an insert trigger for the `users` table, which will increment the sequence number for the given initials and return it back to generate the UID:

```
delimiter //
create trigger users_before_insert before insert on users
for each row begin
  set @initials = concat(left(new.fname,1), left(new.lname, 1));
  insert into uid_seq (initials, seq)
    values (@initials, last_insert_id(1))
    on duplicate key update seq = last_insert_id(seq + 1);
  set new.uid = concat(@initials, lpad(last_insert_id(), 3, 0));
end //
delimiter ;
```

This method is concurrency safe, because we use `INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ..` and return the generated value using `LAST_INSERT_ID()`. This way two users will never get the same UID. In worst case you might burn a sequence number, when the server crashes while processing the insert. However - If you execute your insert in a transaction, that shouldn't happen too.

Note that you still need an AUTO_INCREMENT ID, because this is the only way to find out, which row you have just inserted, unless you have a natural identifying key.